# t6963 GLCD very low contrast

Tags: microcontroller, c, lcd, microprocessor, glcd

I am trying to setup a 240x128 GLCD with t6963c driver ([datasheet](http://www.tme.vn/upload/pdf/TS240128D.pdf)). I am familiar with ks0108 drivers but newbie in t6963. 
I have written a simple code with only lcd-init() that I expect to see the cursor blinking.
Here are the problems:

1. GLCD seems to receive codes (commands and data) correctly because a blinking cursor can be seen but the contrast is very very low such that it can be seen only in a dark room. I have connected VOUT ( the -15 volt producing pin: 18) to a potentiometer and the other side of the pot is connected to the ground, the wiper to VO (pin:4) and set the pot to maximum contrast. I even tried it by connecting VOUT directly to VO but the same contrast!
2. the cursor seems to blink in an incorrect position and changes its position every time I turn the module on and with different heights!

What am I missing? is it a problem in my setup?

```
void lcd_init(void)
{

    GLCD_CTRL_PORT=0xFF;
    SET_FONT8x8;   // all ctrl bit =1 except FS.  FS=0 means font size=8x8  FS=1 fontsize=6x8
    GLCD_CTRL_DDR=0xFF;

    GLCD_DATA_PORT=0x00;
    GLCD_DATA_DDR=0xFF;

    //all contorl lines high:
    SET_WR;
    SET_RD;
    SET_CE;
    SET_CD;

    CLEAR_RESET;
    _delay_ms(DELAY);
    SET_RESET;
    SET_FONT8x8;

    fontSize=8;
    charsPerRow=NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS/fontSize;


    GLCD_WriteCommand(GRAPHICS_OFF | TEXT_OFF | CURSOR_OFF);  //reset settings

    GLCD_GraphicsSetup(); //set home address and area
    GLCD_TextSetup();     //set home address and area

    GLCD_WriteCommand(TEXT_ONLY_MODE | CGROM_MODE); //mode

    GLCD_WriteCommand(GRAPHICS_ON | TEXT_ON | CURSOR_ON | CURSOR_BLINK_ON);  //turn on settings

    GLCD_CursorSetup();


    GLCD_cursorSetXY(0,0);


}

void GLCD_TextSetup(){

    GLCD_WriteDataW(TEXT_HOME);
    GLCD_WriteCommand(TEXT_HOME_SET_COMMAND);

    GLCD_WriteDataW(charsPerRow);
    GLCD_WriteCommand(TEXT_AREA_SET_COMMAND);
}


void GLCD_GraphicsSetup(){

    GLCD_WriteDataW(GRAPHICS_HOME);
    GLCD_WriteCommand(GRAPHICS_HOME_SET_COMMAND);

    GLCD_WriteDataW(charsPerRow);
    GLCD_WriteCommand(GRAPHICS_AREA_SET_COMMAND);
}


void GLCD_CursorSetup(){

    GLCD_WriteCommand(CURSOR_PATTERN | CURSOR_HEIGHT); // cursor height

    GLCD_WriteDataW(CURSOR_HOME);    //set cursor pointer to memory
    GLCD_WriteCommand(CURSOR_HOME_SET_COMMAND);
}

void GLCD_cursorSetXY(char X,char Y){

    GLCD_WriteData(X);
    GLCD_WriteData(Y);
    GLCD_WriteCommand(CURSOR_POSITION_SET_COMMAND);

}

unsigned char GLCD_ChceckStatus(void) 
{
    unsigned char lcdStatus;
    GLCD_DATA_DDR = 0x00;  //make it ready to accept status


    SET_CD; //command
    SET_WR; //no write
    CLEAR_RD; //read

    CLEAR_CE; //pulse on chip enable and read status
    _delay_ms(DELAY);
    lcdStatus = GLCD_DATA_PIN;

    SET_CE; //no CE anymore
    SET_RD; //no read anymore

    GLCD_DATA_DDR = 0xFF;
    return lcdStatus;
}

void GLCD_WriteCommand( char command)
{

    while(!(GLCD_ChceckStatus()&0x03));
    GLCD_DATA_PORT = command;

    SET_CD;
    SET_RD; // no read
    CLEAR_WR; //write


    PULSE_CE;

    SET_WR;  //no write anymore

}

void GLCD_WriteData( char data)
{

    while(!(GLCD_ChceckStatus()&0x03));
    CLEAR_CD;  //data
    GLCD_DATA_PORT = data;

    SET_RD;     //no read
    CLEAR_WR;  //write

    PULSE_CE;

    SET_WR;  //no write anymore
    SET_CD;  //no data anymore

}

void GLCD_WriteDataW(int data)
{

    GLCD_WriteData(data & 0XFF);
    GLCD_WriteData(data>>8);

}
```

and the values are:

```
#define GRAPHICS_OFF        0x90
#define GRAPHICS_ON         0x98 
#define TEXT_OFF            0x90
#define TEXT_ON             0x94
#define CURSOR_OFF          0x90
#define CURSOR_ON           0x92
#define CURSOR_BLINK_OFF    0x90
#define CURSOR_BLINK_ON     0x91

#define CURSOR_PATTERN      0xA0

#define TEXT_HOME_SET_COMMAND  0x40
#define TEXT_AREA_SET_COMMAND  0x41

#define GRAPHICS_HOME_SET_COMMAND  0x42
#define GRAPHICS_AREA_SET_COMMAND  0x43

#define CURSOR_HOME_SET_COMMAND   0x24
#define CURSOR_POSITION_SET_COMMAND  0x21


#define CGROM_MODE   0x80
#define CGRAM_MODE   0x88
#define EXOR_MODE    0x81
#define OR_MODE      0x80
#define AND_MODE     0x83
#define TEXT_ONLY_MODE 0x84
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The power dissipation of the module was higher than what is written in the data sheet and it caused voltage drop.
By using a stronger power supply (LM7805 + TIP2955 ) the contrast is ok now.

Comment: And what about the cursor position?

Comment: I managed to fix it but there is another problem: I can not clear the screen !